# More efficient accumulator in SQL?

Tags: aggregate, clickhouse

I'm writing a ledger system where every transaction can have multiple classifications. For example, if someone purchases a widget for $50, I can categorize that transaction as having an account of "Revenue" and an SKU as "SKU1".

Users can then select the dimensions they wish to report on, and I can generate aggregates.

When my database has 10M+ transactions, the following query is prohibitively slow. After about 10s I receive a  `Memory limit exceeded` error on my 8GB laptop.

Thus the question: I don't actually care about the individual rows, I only care about the accumulation of these values. In my test, I only expect about 10 rows returned after aggregation.

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a7d8/10/0

```sql
select
   year,
   sum(amount),
   t1.value as account,
   t2.value as sku
from 
    transactions 
left join
    tags t1 on transactions.id = t1.transaction_id and t1.name ='account'
left join
    tags t2 on transactions.id = t2.transaction_id and t2.name = 'sku'
group by
    year,
    t1.value,
    t2.value;
```

Here is the query plan:

```
Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))
  Aggregating
    Expression (Before GROUP BY)
      Join (JOIN)
        Expression ((Before JOIN + (Projection + Before ORDER BY)))
          Join (JOIN)
            Expression (Before JOIN)
              ReadFromMergeTree (default.transactions)
            Expression ((Joined actions + (Rename joined columns + (Projection + Before ORDER BY))))
              ReadFromMergeTree (default.tags)
        Expression ((Joined actions + (Rename joined columns + (Projection + Before ORDER BY))))
          ReadFromMergeTree (default.tags)
```

And, finally, here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE default.transactions
(
    `id` Int32,
    `date` Date,
    `amount` Float32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY id
ORDER BY id
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192

CREATE TABLE default.tags
(
    `transaction_id` Int32,
    `name` String,
    `value` String,
    INDEX idx_tag_value value TYPE set(0) GRANULARITY 4,
    INDEX idx_tag_name name TYPE set(0) GRANULARITY 4
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id, name)
ORDER BY (transaction_id, name)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

My questions are:

- Is there a different schema, or different set of Clickhouse features I might use?
- Should I instead pre-compute aggregates?
- Is there a different DB which can perform this kind of calculation more efficiently?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: "*query is prohibitively slow*" - What is considered prohibitively slow? SQLite isn't really designed for heavy OLAP / aggregation type queries, rather it's more of an OLTP specific database, which may be part of your issue here. (Though it's generally not terrible at the task either, so I'd be surprised if 10 million rows of aggregation was choking it up significantly?). I don't know much about Clickhouse, but my understanding is it is an OLAP oriented database and should handle such type of query better. But hard to say for your situation without some form of execution plan information.

Comment: I have updated my question with a query plan and made the question specific to Clickhouse.

Answer (score 0):

Clickhouse is notoriously memory-hungry, and not really suitable for running on a single node with just 8 Gi of memory. I suggest you choose something more suitable for your "infrastructure". For example, Postgres won't have any problem aggregating 10 million rows.

Also, your model looks suspiciously like EAV, which is a very bad thing for analytics queries. If you insist on using Clickhouse, denormalise your model.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll give this a try in Postgres! Clickhouse is not a requirement for this project. I was not familiar with the term EAV, but yes, it looks like that describes my model. If you have pointers, beyond the wikipedia page, for techniques to reason about this, then I'm all ears.

Comment: There have been many posts about EAV [on this site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eav?tab=Votes).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works with Clickhouse. Rather than having two tables (`transactions` and `tags`), one can create a column for tags with a [Map](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/map) type.

The new structure would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE default.transactions
(
    `id` Int32,
    `date` Date,
    `amount` Float32,
    `tags` Map(String, String),
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY id
```

From there, you could query:

```
SELECT
  year,
  SUM(amount),
  tags['account'],
  tags['sku']
FROM
  transactions
GROUP BY
  year,
  tags['account'],
  tags['sku']
```

When I run this against a table with 280M rows, it is able to return in 7 seconds.